# Programmatically set custom properties of term

Tags: term-store, term-set

Currently I'm trying yo store custom values of terms in terms store,

```
.Terms Store

 .AAA(Group)

  .Location(TermSet)

   .StamFord(Term)

    .Mumbai
```

`StamFord Location` has a custom property ,trying to store that custom property programmatically. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

The Term object contains a method called "SetCustomProperty(key, value)". Remember to commit your changes on the term object after setting or editing a custom property. The user running this code needs to be a TermStore Administrator, otherwise you will get a UnauthorizedException.

It could look like this:

```
termObject.SetCustomProperty("SomeKey", "Some Value");

try
{
    termObject.TermStore.CommitAll();
}
catch (Exception)
{
    termObject.TermStore.RollbackAll();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The property you're looking for is called a `LocalCustomProperty` or a `SharedCustomProperty` depending on which type of custom property you want to set.

Term documentation: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.term_members.aspx)

More specifically the `Term.SetLocalCustomProperty` method: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.taxonomy.term.setlocalcustomproperty.aspx)

For apps / online: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn312560.aspx)